# Automapper Profile with Dependency on another Profile

Tags: c#, automapper

I am in the same situation with these questions:

1. [How to map property of type `Object` with different datatypes to a corresponding classtype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689294/how-to-map-property-of-type-object-with-different-datatypes-to-a-corresponding)
2. [AutoMapper Object Collections not mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823088/automapper-object-collections-not-mapping)

Here is an example:

```
namespace Request
{
    public class Source
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Class1", typeof(Class1))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Class2", typeof(Class2))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Class3", typeof(Class3))]
        public object Item { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1 { ... }
    public class Class2 { ... }
    public class Class3 { ... }
}

namespace Response
{
    public class Destination
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Class1", typeof(Class1))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Class2", typeof(Class2))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Class3", typeof(Class3))]
        public object Item { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1 { ... }
    public class Class2 { ... }
    public class Class3 { ... }
}
```

`AutoMapper` doesn't consider the `XmlElementAttribute` for mapping properties like this. I was able to solve it by using reflection:

```
public object Map(object source, Type destinationParentType, string destinationPropertyName)
{
    var prop = destinationParentType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).SingleOrDefault(p =>
        string.Compare(p.Name, destinationPropertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0);

    if (prop == null || prop.CustomAttributes == null) return null;

    var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(prop, typeof(XmlElementAttribute))
        .Cast<XmlElementAttribute>().SingleOrDefault(a =>
            string.Compare(a.Type.Name, source.GetType().Name, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0);

    return attribute == null ? null : AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(source, source.GetType(), attribute.Type);
}
```

by calling it like this:

```
CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Item, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => Map(s.Item, typeof(DestinationType), "Item")));
```

Basically, I will just determine the actual type of the `source` and get the matching type on the `destination`, and then proceed with the simple mapping.

My problem now is we need to do it with `DependencyInjection`, so I created the following profiles:

Main:

```
public class MainProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    [Dependency]
    internal AttributeMapper AttributeMapper { get; set; } <--This is not resolved

    public MainProfile()
    {
        CreateMap ...
        CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Item, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => AttributeMapper.Map(s.Item, typeof(DestinationType), "Item")));
                                                             ^-- this instance is null
    }
}
```

Then the mapper for the properties with `XmlElementAttributes`:

```
public class AttributeProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public AttributeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source.Class1, Destination.Class1>();
        CreateMap<Source.Class2, Destination.Class2>();
        CreateMap<Source.Class3, Destination.Class3>();
    }
}
```

I registered them like this:

```
var mainConfig = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.AddProfile<MainProfile>();
    //Other Profiles
});

var helperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(c => 
{ 
    c.AddProfile<AttributeProfile>(); 
});

Container.RegisterType<AttributeMapper>();
Container.RegisterInstance(mainConfig.CreateMapper(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
Container.RegisterInstance("AttributeMapper", helperConfig.CreateMapper(),
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Then my AttributeMapper class is this:

```
public class AttributeMapper
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AttributeMapper([Dependency("AttributeMapper")] IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public object Map(object source, Type destinationParentType, string destinationPropertyName)
    {
        //Same method from the one above, but I am using _mapper instead of AutoMapper.Mapper.Map    
        return attribute == null ? null : _mapper.Map(source, source.GetType(), attribute.Type);
    }
}
```

But I am getting an `Object Refence not set to an instance of an object` in the `AttributeMapper` property of the `MainProfile` class.

Is `Dependency` an issue for `AutoMapper` profiles that's why I cannot make this work? Is there any other way to fix this `XmlElementAttributes` mapping using `AutoMapper`?

I am open for alternative ways that can help.

Comment: Profiles are singletons, you need to inject into your resolver. See [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html).

Comment: When you want to combine DI with constructor logic, the most reasonable approach would be constructor injection instead of property injection, right?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank, somehow i am getting there.

Comment: @grek40 if you are pertaining to the `Profile` classes, I cannot inject the dependency through the constructor. But I am not so sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Lucian Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700) for sharing his idea. I would mark your comment as answer if I could.

I created an `XmlElementAttributeResolver` (a more generic name would be appropriate) as follows:

```
public class XmlElementAttributeResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, object>
{
    public object Resolve(object source, object destination, object sourceMember, object destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var sourceMemberType = sourceMember.GetType();
        var destinationNamespace = destination.GetType().Namespace;
        var destinationMemberType = destination.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == sourceMemberType.Name && t.Namespace == destinationNamespace);

        return destinationMemberType == null
            ? null
            : context.Mapper.Map(sourceMember, sourceMemberType, destinationMemberType);
    }
}
```

Using the resolver in my `MainProfile` removed the dependency to my `AttributeMapper` earlier:

```
public class MainProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    //[Dependency]
    //internal AttributeMapper AttributeMapper { get; set; } <--This is not resolved from UnityContainer

    public MainProfile()
    {
        CreateMap ...
        CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Item, o => o.ResolveUsing<XmlElementAttributeResolver, object>(s => s.Item));
    }
}
```

And since resolvers have `RuntimeMapper` in the `ResolutionContext` argument, I do not need to inject my mapper to the resolver. Hence, my container for mapper has been simpler:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.AddProfile<MainProfile>();
    //Other Profiles
});

Container.RegisterInstance(config.CreateMapper(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```